# Why isn't fread, fwrite or fseek working properly for me? - C

Tags: c, file, binary, fwrite, fseek

I have the following problem, which I have been trying to figure out but I still can't.

I have a binary file that has 1000 random integers from 0-9, the code which I have done this with:

```
int main() {

FILE *fp;
int r, i;

char fp_string[600] = "/Users/mac/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/College/Program With Persistent Data/Lab 3/num1000.bin";

fp = fopen(fp_string, "wb+");

srand(time(NULL));

for (i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    r = rand()%10; //returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and 20
    fwrite(&r, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

}

fclose(fp);

return 0;
```

}

Okay so that works fine, now the problem comes now. If I try to use fseek to change the third value, and then read it, it won't work.

```
int main() {
FILE *fp;
int r, i;

char fp_string[600] = "/Users/mac/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/College/Program With Persistent Data/Lab 3/num1000.bin";

fp = fopen(fp_string, "wb+");

r = 9;

if (fseek(fp, 3, SEEK_SET) == 0) {
    fwrite(&r, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fseek(fp, 3, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    printf("\n\nr = %d, i = %d \n\n", r, i);
}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

}

'i' and 'r' are the same numbers numbers but, I tried to display all the numbers and they are all changed (as I show bellow). I have looked everywhere and I still can't find anything.

Displaying numbers before using fseek and fwrite:

> 7 0 8 9 6 2 0 3 4 2 5 7 7 1 1 6 7 9 8 0 8 9 8 0 2 3 1 1 3 8 1 9 8 8 2 7 6 1 5 8 0 8 3 4 9 1 5 2 2 8 2 0 9 8 5 1 8 4 2 4 8 1 2 5 2 0 6 6 1 1 0 8 6 1 3 1 4 0 9 9 7 0 1 8 1 7 9 6 3 0 6 5 7 6 5 3 4 1 1 3 5 6 0 3 2 7 9 7 3 1 5 8 2 3 4 5 0 5 0 2 4 6 8 8 1 2 4 7 4 0 7 0 3 6 2 4 9 8 3 0 3 6 5 0 0 5 3 2 3 9 9 8 3 7 4 5 5 6 8 2 9 6 0 5 7 3 9 4 6 3 2 5 4 6 1 3 1 5 9 6 3 4 1 6 4 5 5 4 3 1 1 7 1 2 1 1 3 0 4 0 4 7 7 0 1 9 8 8 9 6 8 8 2 2 8 7 0 5 5 1 4 0 7 2 0 1 1 7 8 9 6 7 3 3 0 2 5 3 4 1 2 6 5 9 2 6 1 9 5 0 4 1 0 3 4 7 6 6 6 2 7 3 3 2 3 9 8 1 0 5 3 6 6 6 5 4 6 0 0 4 3 9 7 9 5 3 2 9 0 7 8 8 3 1 6 4 7 6 1 8 0 1 6 1 8 8 3 3 5 9 9 0 8 6 2 1 7 7 8 6 8 8 0 3 0 3 1 4 6 0 2 8 7 0 7 1 1 0 6 9 1 0 3 8 2 0 4 3 1 6 4 8 0 2 2 5 2 2 4 6 4 7 1 7 1 2 9 5 8 9 0 2 4 9 2 3 0 8 9 1 8 1 7 9 2 3 7 8 7 7 1 3 2 8 8 3 5 5 1 4 2 0 7 5 3 0 8 8 8 6 7 2 6 8 6 3 0 5 8 0 2 4 8 7 9 5 8 6 2 2 4 7 3 3 4 5 5 2 9 7 5 8 3 9 9 0 1 9 5 6 2 6 7 1 9 8 4 9 5 6 1 6 3 0 7 1 6 6 2 3 8 9 6 8 2 1 5 9 5 5 3 4 9 8 7 4 6 2 0 2 1 6 6 5 0 2 4 8 8 6 0 9 4 9 1 1 5 7 6 2 2 6 2 1 7 0 2 9 1 6 8 7 1 8 9 6 6 2 8 1 8 2 0 9 5 9 0 0 0 6 4 4 8 8 4 9 3 2 1 3 7 1 2 2 1 9 0 0 2 8 1 3 6 9 5 7 9 9 1 7 2 1 3 9 1 4 4 9 3 6 7 5 9 6 8 0 7 2 1 3 0 7 3 8 9 5 0 4 9 6 5 6 7 4 9 1 9 8 2 2 2 9 6 7 0 1 0 2 4 9 9 8 8 6 2 1 2 5 8 6 2 3 8 1 4 6 0 7 8 1 5 6 2 4 4 1 2 3 8 4 6 1 6 9 0 0 9 8 7 7 5 7 9 1 4 7 5 3 0 6 8 1 1 3 1 4 7 6 9 5 7 4 0 1 8 3 0 9 3 5 9 2 4 9 3 1 8 1 9 6 5 5 4 3 6 7 6 2 1 0 1 2 0 4 1 3 7 1 2 0 1 5 5 8 5 9 7 3 0 7 3 5 7 9 1 5 2 9 6 5 9 0 9 5 4 0 4 1 6 6 1 6 8 7 7 5 1 9 8 9 1 9 4 1 5 9 5 3 5 5 1 5 9 7 4 9 0 7 1 9 5 9 6 3 0 2 7 9 3 7 5 4 6 8 7 9 6 5 8 1 8 1 9 5 2 0 5 5 4 7 0 2 2 1 9 9 7 3 4 9 7 9 0 0 1 1 8 1 7 6 5 0 4 0 4 7 1 0 3 2 5 9 3 4 4 1 6 1 0 9 8 2 1 3 9 4 5 8 0 6 7 5 6 5 3 5 4 0 4 0 0 7 7 0 5 2 3 0 6 8 9 9 1 8 0 1 4 1 2 9 4 6 6 4 1 3 4 7 0 6 5 9 6 6 3 5 4 9 6 2 6 4 9 0 8 2 1 4 8 8 0 9 5 4 2 9 6 0 2 8 0 8 9 5 0 1 6 5 4 8 4 4 9 8 8 1 4 5 1 0 3 6 9 0 2 2 4 3 9 9 5 4 0 1 4 5 2 5 8 8 6 9 7 9 9 7 2 7 1 3 8 9 1 7 2 8 5 9 1 5 8 5 5 7 3 6 3 9 4 5

Displaying numbers after using fseek and fwrite:

> 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944     150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944 150994944

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: there is no loop in the second program. how do you get the second output? or is that the contents of the file?

Comment: How are you able to read when you fopen without the 'r' flag

Comment: "If I try to use fseek to change the third value,..."   `fseek(fp, 3,SEEK_SET)` will seek to the third *byte*, not the third value.

Comment: To read the file, i just get the first program and change fwrite to fread, with reading permission. Thanks for your help. I was just reading to see what it was written there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line in the second listing:

```
fp = fopen(fp_string, "wb+");
```

You're truncating the file to zero length.

You want:

```
fp = fopen(fp_string, "rb+");
```

Reference: [fopen - open a stream](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know rb+ was a thing.

Comment: Am I using fseek properly there?

Comment: No, you need to do `fseek(fp, 3 * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET)`

Comment: Ohhhh okay, thanks a million for your time and help :)